# Building an OAuth2.0 client application when resource and auth server is Microsoft 365, using MS-Graph API

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar, outlook-calendar

I am trying to build an OAuth2.0 client (Authorization code flow) app communicating with the world of Microsoft, using Microsoft-Graph API. The goal is to do some proof of concept of getting the user's calendar data and also notifications when the user adds some events to the Outlook calendar.

It is a Java app so I am using Microsoft-Graph API's Java SDK, the problem is I couldn't find a proper multi-tenant tutorial using which I can cater to all MS identities including work/school/personal accounts. Most tutorials by MS are geared toward single-tenant in-house apps supposed to be used by users present in the same tenant wherein the app is registered. Any help shall be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Have you register your app in azure - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: Thanks for replying and providing the web link, I couldn't reach up to this on my own, was spending time in MS-Graph docs only.

Comment: I am trying to use this (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/tree/main/4.%20Spring%20Framework%20Web%20App%20Tutorial/2-Authorization-I/call-graph) tutorial for multi-tenant  (by making the tenant-id: common) but no success, could you please guide.

Comment: you mean , you haven't tried in your local ,if you are just looking for a proper doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant .

Comment: Could you please also explain what you tried and what you faced issue , so will help you further .thanks

Comment: Thanks for supporting me, I am working on the same set of documents you just referred to above, and I shall be coming up with a proper question and what problem I am facing in a few.

Comment: @vickykumar thanks for extending help, as it is hard to explain the problem statement and status in a comment, I created a new question explaining what I tried as well. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73806207/how-to-integrate-a-spring-boot-java-app-with-outlook-calendar-for-ms-personal-ac

Comment: @vickykumar Hey, I am trying to build an OAuth2.0 client application that can fetch Outlook calendar data for the MS personal account holders,  all the starting code examples are geared towards users in a tenant and I couldn't find one with which personal account holders can be reached, any help shall be appcreciated.